# How to save file into Azure Storage Account in the release pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-storage-account

I am trying to publish 2 files `1.ext, 2.ext` into a General purpouse v2 storage account that I've just created, I've created a file share inside of it.

**Question:** How to save/publish a file into storage account from Azure DevOps pipeline? Which task should I use? Azure copy seems to have only two types of storage avaiable:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `Azure file copy` task.

[image]

Run the pipeline, the file will be uploaded to target storage account:

[image]

Anyway, you can also use `Azure PowerShell` or `Azure CLI` task to upload file to storage account. Here are the tutorial for [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell) and [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-cli)

---

**Update**

The `Source` could be a file or a folder path, so you can:

1. Filter target files by PowerShell task in previous task, and copy it to a temporary folder.
2. Upload the whole folder.

For example: I just uploaded the whole project source files by setting the path to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`

[image]

And then, all the files were uploaded to storage account.

Comment: I did that, it works! but it seems that this task does not support wildcards for the source location. Is there any alternative where I could provide wildcards/regex for the source directory?

Comment: A workaround is to use PowerShell task to filter target files and copy them to a temporary folder, then you can upload the whole temporary folder. Check my updates.